# Quick beginner CSS, how to "scope" styles?

Tags: html, css

Excuse the poor phrasing, I know it's possible but I can't figure out what to google so I'll just explain it like so..

I have this html:

```
<div class="navbar_links">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.google.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="www.google.com">About</a></li>
<li><a href="www.google.com">Speakers</a></li>
<li><a href="www.google.com">Exhibitors</a></li>
<li><a href="www.google.com">Agenda</a></li>
<li><a href="www.google.com">Location</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and then later on I might have another list..

All I want to do is style just the `<ul> / <li>` items for the class `navbar_links`. Not for any occurrence of an unordered list in the html, just an unordered list found within `<div class="navbar_links">` Could someone explain to me how to do that? And for future reference, let me know what it's "called" so I don't have to waste SO's time with something I know I should have been able to google, sorry :P

Comment: Unless you have have specific reason to, you dont need to wrap a `<ul>` in a `<div>`, so it can become  `<ul class="navbar_links">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to limit a css to only apply to what is in a content area and not the entire page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189076/is-there-a-way-to-limit-a-css-to-only-apply-to-what-is-in-a-content-area-and-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for CSS selectors: [www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

In this case, you can write the following:

```
.navbar_links ul {
  /* put styles for ul here */
}
```

Comment: Selected as answer since you were first to tell me what selectors where called as well as how to use one :) Thanks to everyone though!

Answer (score 7):

Use `.navbar_links ul` or `.navbar_links li` depending on what you actually want to style. This will restrict the styling to only those items that fall inside the `navbar_links` class.

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
.navbar_links ul
```

Here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWWmc/1

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

```
.navbar_links ul
```

to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are called *CSS Selectors* or more specifically, the *class selector*. e.g.

```
.navbar_links ul, /* Select all ul within elements of class='navbar_links' */
.navbar_links ul > li /* Select all li that are *children* of a ul within els of class='navbar_links' */
```

(The second example would not select the inner `li` of `<div class='navbar_links'><ul><li><ol><li>…`)